# What is a bd build of Debian?

Tags: debian, images

When I look at the [alpha releases of Bullseye (non-free)](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/bullseye_di_alpha2/amd64/) I see a lot of BD images. What are these?

Comment: Makes me wonder why we still pretend someone will download this to something that is not a USB-stick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly sure why but BD is "Blu-Ray". I found this only in the [mirroring docs](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/bullseye_di_alpha2/amd64/)

> `*-bd.iso` (single-layer Blu-Rays): As above, except that individual images are up to 23 GB in size. These images are only available as jigdo files for a limited set of architectures (amd64 and i386) and source.

Answer (score 5):

Other `bd` images are listed [on the download pages](https://www.debian.org/CD/jigdo-cd/), as “Blu-ray”. “BD” stands for “Blu-ray Disc”, which is the official term for such media (see for example [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blu-ray)).

Answer (score 4):

From the DebianEdu wiki: [What is a BD image?](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianEdu/GetACopy#What_is_a_BD_image.3F)

> It takes more than 5 GB, so it will fit only on larger USB memory sticks, double layer DVD or Blu-ray Disc (BD). This ISO will take longer to download as it is a full offline installation medium that can be used without requiring an Internet connection.
>
> If you plan to administer a Debian Edu network it is strongly encouraged that you keep such a copy near you. Repositories are reliable and will almost never fail but even so, if you are responsible about keeping a system up and running this can be a real life saver when worst situations arise.